# ICollectionView CurrentPosition is -1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icollectionview

I have a `ICollectionView` from a `ObservableCollection`,

```
 WorkingSpreadOrderCollevtionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SpreadOrderCollection);
```

my `SpreadOrderCollection` is not empty, as can be seen the `SourceCollection` count is 1

[image: ICollectionView Watch]

But why the `CurrentPosition` is `-1`, and I think because of this, `DataGrid`  is not showing anything even I have bind the `WorkingSpreadOrderCollevtionView` to its `ItemSourcce`.

May I know what is the possible bug here?

==========================================================

Edit: The `xaml` `binding` is as follow, the `DataContext` is pretty sure to be correct as another `public` property in the same `ViewModel` is bind to the same `xaml` correctly.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WorkingSpreadOrderCollevtionView}" CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
</DataGrid>
```

In addition, I can see the `Columns` autogenerated in the datagrid, but I just cant see the record.

==================================================

Update: I have found the dumb bug. I have called `GetDefaultView` twice and thinking two difference copies of the view is created, and thus applied two filters on the "two" copies. The second filter prevented the records from showing in the `DataGrid`. What I have done now is to create a new view as per below,

```
WorkingSpreadOrderCollevtionView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = SpreadOrderCollection }.View;
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

`CurrentPosition` usually indicates selected record.
`Selector` descendants can synchronize their `SelectedItem`/`SelectedItemIndex` with `ICollectionView.CurrentItem`/`CurrentPosition`.

The -1 value just means, that there is no selected item in the selector/collection view.

This is not related to the problem of empty `DataGrid`.